# Windows Forms Chart - column series not plotting from zero on y axis

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I have an MS chart control with several StepLine series and one column series.

All series are plotted by doing:

```
double yvalue = ...;
Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now, new object[] {yvalue});
```

the series in question is defined in the designer:

```
        series31.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series31.Color = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
        series31.CustomProperties = "EmptyPointValue=Zero, MaxPixelPointWidth=1";
        series31.Legend = "Legend1";
        series31.MarkerSize = 1;
```

Step lines plot fine, however the column series is displayed with a line going from the bottom of the chart to the value (in the screen cap below, the value is typically around 2.0).

How can I get the series to just draw a line that starts at 0 on the y-axis?

[image: chart display]

Comment: You will have to show more code or look deeper into your values. With positive yvalues the columns should not go down below zero. Use the debugger to check those points!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a chart that will start from zero in Y-Axis at the bottom.

```
chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
```

if you do so,then you will not see the value less then zero in chart.you can also set the Maximum of 
Y-Axis.

```
chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = 10;
```

above code will show only the values from 0 to 10.